# document.querySelectorAll after a form submission

Tags: javascript

I've been struggling for more than 2 hours to make 2 lines of code works. My problem is that my code works when the content is loaded with the DOM, but when I add the content to my div using a form the code stops working. How do I do to make it work?

Here is the code I'm trying to push in my function:

```
newKeywordHtmlStr += '<div style="padding: 6px;border-bottom: #b5aeae; border-bottom-style: solid;border-bottom-width: 1px;"><span id="term'+ i +'">' + arraySearchTerms[i] + "</span><span style='float: right;'><button type='button' id='button"+ i +"'>Submit</button></span></div>";
container.push('term'+ i);
```

Outside the function, I have 2 var that will extract the content I want to process:

```
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
var spans = document.querySelectorAll('span');
```

I've tried to create an array "container" that contain term+ i and replace:

```
 var spans = document.querySelectorAll('span');
```

By:

```
var spans = container;
```

But it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong here?
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: `using a form` - so, are you doing some AJAX in the form submit? if so, are you preventing the default form submit action, which will load a new page of course

Comment: can you share full code here?

Comment: I have a form that I add a list of words to, then I submit it and the words are split and added to arraySearchTerms array and added after that to a div.

Comment: No Ajax, but javascript, so the page doesn't reload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I added submit button and it's Functionality**

On click of Submit button data will be append in a `Div`(i.e.container)

```js
$('.send-btn').click(function () {
    var textAreaVal = document.getElementById("myTextarea").value;
    if(textAreaVal && textAreaVal!=""){
       var lines = textAreaVal.split(/\n/);
       //console.log(lines);
       $.each(lines, function( i, line ) {
          //console.log( i + ": " + line );
          var arraySearchTerms = line.split(" ");
          var newKeywordHtmlStr='<div style="padding: 6px;border-bottom: #b5aeae; border-bottom-style: solid;border-bottom-width: 1px;">';
             $.each(arraySearchTerms, function(index, value){
                newKeywordHtmlStr += "<span id=term"+ index +"> "+ value + "</span>";
            });
        newKeywordHtmlStr += "<span style='float: right;'><button type='button' id='button"+  i +"'>Submit</button></span></div>";
       $(".container").append(newKeywordHtmlStr);
      });
     }
    var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
    var spans = document.querySelectorAll('span');
    for (var i=0; i<spans.length; ++i) {
      spans[i].addEventListener('click', clickFuncSpan);
    }
    for (var i=0; i<buttons.length; ++i) {
       buttons[i].addEventListener('click', clickFunc);
    }
   return false;
});



function clickFunc() {
 var selected = [];
 // alert(this.id); 
 // alert(this.previousElementSibling.innerHTML);
  $(this).closest('div').find("span").map(function(){
     if($(this).hasClass( "underline" )){
          selected.push($(this).html());
     }
  })
 console.log(selected.join(','));
}

function clickFuncSpan(e) {
 e.target.classList.add("underline");
}
```

```css
span.underline {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: blue;
}

span {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<form action="">
<textarea id="myTextarea"></textarea>
   <input type="Submit" value="Form Submit" class="send-btn"/>
   <div class="container"></div>
   </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me. Again :) I'm sorry but it's not how my code is meant to work. At first, nothing is in the body then I add some random words in the textarea and submit. The span and button are then created. That's when my problem occurs. Your help is much appreciated, don't hesitate to ask for more information if my explainations are not clear. Thank you again.

Comment: @CreekBarbara- I updated with working set for you.Hope this will resolve your problem completely